# Interpretation of coefficients in multinomial LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS model output in scala

Tags: scala, regression, apache-spark-mllib, multinomial

I am attempting to do some post processing of the outputs of a multinomial LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS model. The model matrix is created in R and then exported to scala spark for model fitting.

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS) states that there is "standard feature scaling and L2 regularization". The outputs of the multinomial model from the `multinom()` function in R's `{nnet}` package is clear as log-odds between a given outcome and a base outcome. There is however not sufficient detailed information in the documentation about how the weights of the LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS can be transformed to obtain a standard set of coefficients.

The term "standard feature scaling" means different things to different people. It could mean that the model matrix is scaled as (x - mean(x))/sd(x) or (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) or a set of other possibilities. In addition the weights output is a string of numbers that is a multiple of the features that could be folded in different ways to obtain a coefficients matrix - for example by row, by column, or some other arbitrary way.

How do I process the outputs from the LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().weights to obtain a standard set of coefficients that I can do some post processing, basic inference and predictions with the original model matrix?